# Regex to ignore leading characters

Tags: java, regex

I'm sure there's a simple solution to this but it's got me stuck so hopefully someone can give me a hand. I've got multiple lines of input that look like this:

```
FooABC
Foo XYZ123
FooFgh
```

I need a regex (in Java) that will give me:

```
ABC
XYZ123
Fgh
```

The best I've come up with so far is:

```
[^Foo\s?].*$
```

Which I thought was working until I noticed that it was removing the capital F from Fgh. Is there any way I can make it exactly ignore the first three characters and one or more whitespace characters then just capture everything else?

**EDIT / CLARIFICATION**

I should have said that I can't use substring / replace or any of the things I would normally do in this situation because this regex will be fed into deployed code that can't currently be updated. What the code is doing is this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( regex );
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( data );
matcher.find();
String extracted = matcher.group();
```

and it's then using the extracted string as a key for a look up. So it has to extract the key in one pass.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace

```
^Foo\s*
```

with an empty string. Use `.{3}` if you need 3 arbitrary characters instead of `Foo`.

---

If you need to use match instead of replace, you need to use a capture group:

```
^Foo\s*(.*)$
```

---

The `[^Foo\s?]` is a character class (`[...]`) to match any characters *except (`^`)* an `F`, a `o`, a whitespace (`\s`) or a question mark `?`. That's why the `F` in `Fgh` is also matched. If you want a grouping bracket, use `(?:...)`.

Comment: Thanks, I now understand why it wasn't working and how I could make it work with groups but, and this is important, only if I could specify the group to return e.g matcher.group( 1 ). Is there anyway, without modifying the code, that I could get ^Foo\s*(.*)$ to return group 1? Cheers.

Comment: @wobbly: No. Since the number of whitespaces is undetermined, a lookbehind cannot be used, so that Foo part has to be matched. However, if you are sure about a maximum number of whitespaces (e.g. 10), you can use a lookbehind: `(?<=^Foo\s{0,10}).*$`.

Answer (score 1):

```
^.{3}\s+.*$
```

should do the trick (it matches 3 arbitrary characters at the beginning of the line, one or more whitespaces and then anything up until the end of the line).

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
String text = text.substring(3).trim();
```

or KennyTM's solution

```
String text = text.replaceFirst("^Foo\\s*", "");
```